# Remove user with filter based on SID

Tags: powershell, wmi, user-profile, get-wmiobject

I have some machines with a lot of profiles and would like to remove all of them, except for 3, that are admins.

this would do the job if i wanted to remove everything

```
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_USerProfile -ComputerName $computer | Remove-WmiObject
```

I have tried to do it with the `where` clause and `-filter`, but wasnt successfull.

Here are some examples

```
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_UserProfile -ComputerName $computer | where {($.SID -neq $UserSID)} | Remove-WMIObject
```

...

```
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_USerProfile -ComputerName $computer -Filter "SID = TEST" | Remove-WmiObject
```

EDIT: I almost got it like this:

```
 Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_USerProfile -ComputerName $computer | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.SID -ne "S-1-5-18" -and $_.SID -ne "S-1-5-19" -and $_.SID -ne "S-1-5-20"} |Remove-WmiObject -WhatIf
```

This way i can filter the output but i got an exception

```
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-WmiObject], ArgumentException
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$UserSID = 'S-1-5-18'
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_UserProfile -ComputerName $computer | where {$_.SID -ne $UserSID} | Remove-WmiObject -WhatIf
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_USerProfile -ComputerName $computer -Filter "SID != '$UserSID'" | Remove-WmiObject -WhatIf
```

Comment: With the `-whatif` i could see the profiles that would have been removed, and its right! But when i remove it, i got an ArgumentException

Comment: Does it succeed if you run it on the target computer locally instead of remote?

Comment: No, it returns the same exception